# Sound system icon disappeared

Tags: windows-7, audio, icons

System icon disappeared in my system tray. So I am not able easily and quickly turn off/on sound or change the volume.

I did search the net and found that right click of system bar can take me to the right place where to fix the issue. Well ... it did but the sound icon is off and greyed out so I am not able to change it.

[image: System Icons]

Sound is working fine. I am using Windows7 on lenovo E431. There was no update of Windows or lenovo. Rebooting did not help either.

Any idea how to bring the icon back?

**SOLVED?**

After the latest restart the icon is back.

What helped me was to run the bat file from  http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5662-notification-area-icons-reset-windows-10-a.html

Comment: The volume icon can disappear when there is no audio output detected. I would first try to plug some headphones or any audio device to the audio output port and check if that changes something.

Comment: You can try running `mmsys.cpl` and check what happens. Also you should start CMD as administrator and type `sfc /scannow` and see if it resolves the issue

Comment: I plugged in head phones and waited for an hour and nothing happened.

Comment: `sfc /scannow` returned `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`

Comment: not sure what I can get out of running `mmsys.cpl`. I was there already so many times but I cannot turn on/off icon there.

Comment: When you run `mmsys.cpl` does any device appear? If yes, try to set one to default

Comment: Go to control panel - device manager - open audio inputs and outputs - right click the one that your laptop is using and uninstall it - press action - scan for hardware changes. You can update your question with a screen shot of the device manager window when the audio inputs and outputs are opened if you need more accurate help with the steps.

Comment: After the latest restart the icon is back.

Comment: I'm having the same problem! It is also grayed out exactly as in the image. If I go to "Customize notification icons" (see bottom of image) there it says next to the Volume that the "Audio service is not running". However, it and all its dependencies are running! Moreover, audio works. Moreover, audio volume control works in various players. moreover, you can run the SNDVOL.EXE program and *it* works---it just will not create a volume tray icon!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On windows 7 my volume icon is missing from the system tray](https://superuser.com/questions/205520/on-windows-7-my-volume-icon-is-missing-from-the-system-tray)

Answer (score 0):

I have 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium, on CyberPower mid range gamer from 2011. 
Gigabyte 870A UD3 mobo with RealTech Audio on board.

I found these instructions on the web that enables the RealTech Audio and an orange icon that produces the manager for that audio

For Windows 7, I used this and hope it will work for all Windows flavors:

- Right click on “Computer” or “My Computer”.
- Choose “Manage”.  (Enter your administrator credentials.)
- Select “Device Manager” in the left panel.
- Expand “Sound, video and game controllers”.
- Find your audio driver and right click on it.
- Choose “Disable”.
- Right click on the audio driver again.
- Choose “Enable”.

Source: [Windows 7 sound not working.  How to fix without restarting computer.

            | The Incidental Economist](https://theincidentaleconomist.com/wordpress/windows-7-sound-not-working-how-to-fix-without-restarting-computer/)

The RealTech icon appeared and double clicking it makes that manage dialog appear, where there is a volume control slider. Your application may also have a volume control that may need to be changed.

Comment: If you copied this solution from a web site, you should identify the source.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete, and to avoid plagiarism.

Comment: This came from the direct response to a search for the string:
windows 7 audio icon missing
Under
"People also ask"
click the wedge at "How do I get my sound back on W7? >

URL:
https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&client=firefox-b-1&ei=XXMmW8myF6HMjwTn9YuoCA&q=windows+7+audio+icon+missing&oq=Windows+7+audio+icon&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0j0i30k1l6j0i8i30k1l3.4299924.4300398.0.4303292.2.2.0.0.0.0.342.498.0j1j0j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.496...0i7i30k1j0i8i7i30k1.0.wJMN8JAk5zI

I am new to this site and  trust this satisfies the requirements.

Comment: I encourage you to take the [Tour](/tour) and visit the [Help Center](/help), specifically [How to reference material written by others](/help/referencing).